# R: Understanding How Scheduled Tasks Are Stored When the Computer is Turned Off

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I am working with the R programming language.

I am learning how to repeatedly execute "tasks" (i.e. R scripts) and schedule them at some fixed time intervals. I found out about two different libraries in R that can be used to do this ("taskscheduleR" and "cronR").

In both of these R libraries, it seems that creating and scheduling tasks are generally straightforward:

```
#FIRST WAY: schedule tasks in "taskscheduleR"

library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "helloworld.R", package = "taskscheduleR")

## run script once within 62 seconds
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 62, "%H:%M"))

#SECOND WAY: schedule tasks in "cronR"

f <- system.file(package = "cronR", "extdata", "helloworld.R")
cmd <- cron_rscript(f)
cmd
cron_add(command = cmd, frequency = 'minutely',
id = 'test1', description = 'My process 1', tags = c('lab', 'xyz'))
cron_add(command = cmd, frequency = 'daily', at='7AM', id = 'test2')
cron_njobs()
cron_ls()
cron_clear(ask=TRUE)
cron_ls()
```

**My Question:** I am trying to understand what happens to these tasks when I turn off my computer, close my R session and close my internet connection.

Suppose I have the following tasks in R that I want to run at some fixed interval:

```
## my_script (create some random numbers, put them in a data frame,
## and save this data frame as a "csv" file containing the date/time 
## at which the file was created):

a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,10,10)

my_data = data.frame(a,b)

write.csv(my_data, paste0("my_data", format(Sys.time(), "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M"), ".csv"))

#END TASK

#save the above script as an R file (I am not sure what "extdata" is)
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "my_script.R", package = "taskscheduleR")

## Run every week on Saturday and Sunday at 09:10
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript_sunsat", rscript = myscript, 

                     schedule = "WEEKLY", starttime = "09:10", days = c('SUN', 'SAT'))
```

I had the following questions about how scheduled tasks are stored in the computer, especially when the computer is turned off:

- Once my computer (e.g. laptop) has been turned off and the battery discharges - is it impossible for this task to keep executing?
- After my computer has been turned off and the battery discharges - once I turn the computer back on, will the task resume its schedule automatically or will I have to re-initialize the task?
- After my computer has been turned off and the battery discharges - are previously stored tasks automatically deleted? Or am I required to manually delete them?
- Suppose the task that I created involves SQL style statements that require a connection to a server (e.g. "RODBC", "DBI" libraries), and suppose I want this task to run every Sunday at 11:30 PM - if the connection with this server connection breaks at 11:28 PM and resumes at 11:41 PM : will the task resume, or will I have to wait until next Sunday for the task to run again?
- In general, will missed tasks (because of the computer battery discharging, server connection interruptions, etc.) automatically try to run again immediately after the interruptions - or will you to wait for the next scheduled interval, unless you want to manually override and re-initialize these tasks?

Can someone please explain this?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/taskscheduleR.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/cronR.pdf

Comment: (1) Generally yes, it is impossible for scripts on your computer to run when the computer is powered off. (2) It depends wholly on whether the scheduler has "catch-up"; `cron` by itself does not, for example, I'm not certain about Windows Scheduler. (3) Stored tasks' life-cycle has very little to do with the state of the battery. (4) It depends on how you write the code, it is likely you'll have to start over on that SQL connection. (5) Again, see #3.

Comment: As a followup to @r2evans's comment. For (2), `cron` in Linux/Unix (Mac OSX is Unix based) doesn't execute tasks if the time has passed, but other tools like `anacron` do. See more details at https://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron and https://www.tecmint.com/cron-vs-anacron-schedule-jobs-using-anacron-on-linux/.
Now, `cronR` uses `cron`, so if you need the flexibility of anacron, replicating the syntax should not be complicated.